# Using a VARCHAR vs INT in MySQL across millions of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have a table that has roughly 30,000,000 rows of data sitting inside it.

The table is relatively simple:

```
 +--------------------------------------+
 | TABLE: recipe_locations              |
 +--------------------------------------+
 | INT recipe_id (primary_key)          |
 | TEXT url                             |
 | VARCHAR(128) domain (index)          |
 | VARCHAR(128) tag                     |
 | INT number_ingrediants (index)       |
 +--------------------------------------+
```

Inside the tag, I am attempting to put the one main ingredient of the dish. I want to make this ingredient searchable.

The problem that I am having at the moment is that it is taking quite some time for searches to happen on the `tag` column. Infact, some `LIKE %...%` queries can take up to ten seconds to complete, which is unacceptable for the workload that I want to push to this table.

I was wondering if it would be faster to have another table which has all of the main ingrediants in it, and first search that `tags` table, fetching the IDs, and then doing a `WHERE IN` on the `recipe_locations` table?

The only thing that I could imagine is if the search query was say, "`a`" (-- where there could be hundreds of thousands of matches in the tags table), then getting all of the IDs for the tags would mean doing a subquery with `WHERE IN`, or doing a `LEFT JOIN`. I would like to know if this would hamper my performance of `LIKE` queries as described earlier.

Comment: usually normalizing your data is a good thing.

Comment: You wouldn't do a subselect, you would use a join then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching with LIKE over a VARCHAR field with 30000000 records is probably the worst thing you could do performance-wise. Also having a TEXT field that can potentially get huge on each row as well will make it even slower. So, that table, recipe_locations, should be accessed as little as possible. If I were you, I would create two additional tables:

Table: ingrediants

```
ingrediant_id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
ingrediant_name VARCHAR(128)
```

Table recipe_ingrediants (1:n relationship, you probably want that)

```
recipe_id INTEGER
ingrediant_id INTEGER
```

(define appropiate indexes)

```
select
  r.*
from
  recipe_ingrediants ri
left join
  recipe r on r.recipe_id=ri.recipe_id
left join
  ingrediants i on i.ingrediant_id=ri.ingrediant_id
where
  i.ingrediant_name='SALT'
order by
  something
```

This way the query goes over the biggest table only once. With appropiate index definitions, this would be a lot quicker than what you have now.

Comment: This is actually the direction that I was considering going. Before I was going to go ahead and jump into doing it this way, I was just wondering if there were any other (possibly less obvious?) ways of going about and optimising this particular dataset.

Comment: You could also try to use MySQL's fulltext capabilities instead, keeping your data structure as it is, but I wouldn't recommend it, fulltext search isn't one of MySQL's strongsuits.

Comment: A column amount for the table recipe_ingredients wouldn't come amiss too. But that's the way to go.